# iphone app icon ios 7,8 (3x) for iphone 6

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]
just got xcode 6 gm seed and wanna upload new version to app store. Noticed that now you are suggested to specify Iphone app icon ios 7,8 60pt 3x. Apple has not updated its app icon guide yet. Is logic the same for 3x as 2x files, how do you think? I mean, just make resolution for the case 180x180 and name file Icon-60@3x.png?

Comment: If you are using assets catalog there is no need to set the image name correctly. Also the real image size is shown in the properties pane when you select an icon type in the assets catalog.

Comment: test it with a @3x image that is completely different and see if it appears

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well yes the logic is same, 3x means (60x3), and what I see from the screenshot in your question -  your are using assets catalog so you dont need to worry about the naming convention. Simply drag and drop your icon.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have a 1024x1024 icon that I'm dragging into the spots in the appicon asset catalog. Is that all? or do I need to manually resize the icon to other sizes? I just dragged the 1024x1024 icon to all the slots.